# Upnp library for python

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, upnp, service-discovery

I have written an application in python 2.7. Now I have to add a feature in it, in which it will find the list of DMRs available in the network and then user will select the device from the list and send data from the application to the device.

For this I searched on google for python upnp libraries, and I got these (`coherence`, `miranda-upnp`, `miniupnp`, `pyunpnp`).

I also read about them, but i couldn't figure out which library i should use.

Tell me which library I should use and why ?

Comment: MiniUPnP Project have some latest updates. miranda-upnp is also good. Other I think not any more supported. So I suggest go for MiniUPnP.

Comment: @New_User123 what about brisa module in python ?

Answer (score 4):

MiniUPnPc is actively supported (I'm the maintainer), it is a C library but there is a python module. Here is a good example for how to use it : https://github.com/miniupnp/miniupnp/blob/master/miniupnpc/testupnpigd.py

But you would prefer miranda-upnp if you want to use a 100% python library.

Comment: Miranda UPNP uses readline extensively which is GPL V3 licensed. So if you want to distribute your code commercially, you should not use Miranda UPNP which will have licensing issues.

Comment: Clarification: The above is true only if you link your proprietary code to the GPL library. If you just use it as a separate program and your code communicates with it via a command line or pipes or a socket, then your code does not become GPL, ie it remains proprietary.

Comment: @Marc It also doesn't apply if you use the BSD libedit library, which has a readline compatible interface.